# How to do stop slideup when submenu is active in dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

How to stop slide up when dropdown submenu is active.When submenu is clicked, dropdown slideup, instead of that i need to stop slideup and stay active with the submenu.Can anyone please help me to fix this? Here is the HTML and js code for that

```
<div class="sidebar-menu">
        <ul>
         <li <?php if($this->uri->segment(1)=="cc"){echo 'class="active"';}?> >
             <a href="#">Create Contract</a></li>

          <li class="sidebar-dropdown">
            <a href="#">
             Create Master Data
            </a>
            <div class="sidebar-submenu">
              <ul id="submenu" class=" treeview-menu nav navbar-nav side-nav">
                <li>
                  <a href="#" <?php if($this->uri->segment(2)=="city"){echo 'class="active"';}?> >City</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#" <?php if($this->uri->segment(2)=="business"){echo 'class="active"';}?> >Line of business</a>
                </li>

              </ul>
            </div>
         </li>    

 $(".sidebar-dropdown > a").click(function(e) {
  $(".sidebar-submenu").slideUp(200);

  if (
    $(this)
      .parent()
      .hasClass("active")
  ) {
    $(".sidebar-dropdown").removeClass("active");
    $(this)
      .parent()
      .removeClass("active");
  } else {
    $(".sidebar-dropdown").addClass("active");

    $(this)
      .next(".sidebar-submenu")
      .slideDown(200);
    $(this)
      .parent()
      .addClass("active");
  }
});
```

Comment: hello, so what you want is to click it once to show the sub-menu and then never slide it up again, right? like, one click to slide it down, and then no matter how many times it's clicked again, it should stay down, correct?

Comment: when clicking the main menu, it will show sub menu.In that submenu is clicked and this submenu will active class.In this case stop doing slideup

Comment: whenever main menu is clicking,slideup and slidedown need to perform

Comment: in my code,when submenu is clicking slideup is happening.

Comment: in my code , when ever main menu is clicking,slideup and slidedown happening correctly..

Comment: so when a link in a sub-menu is clicked, you want that sub-menu to become *active* and to remain shown for as long as it is active, even if the parent menu is clicked, correct? then, how is the sub-menu supposed to *lose* its active state?

Comment: if the parent menu clicks slide up and down will happen

Comment: i have attached screenshort

Comment: when clicking create master (main menu) slide up and down will happen.and when  we click submenu(city,line of business) it doesnt allow to slideup

Comment: to sum up, it means that as long as *Invoicing frequency* (or any other element in the sub-menu) is active, that sub-menu is not allowed to slide up, right? and question: what about other sub-menus, can they be slid up/down while there is an active sub-menu?

Comment: yes..not allowed to slideup when clicking submenu

Comment: @Scaramouche plz check my image i have uploaded newly...when clicking create contract this is active now but not sliding up the create master data...submenus are not active now

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were looking for? [Navbar with sub-menu](https://codepen.io/jstneg/pen/pvyYdw)

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul.dropdown-menu [data-toggle=dropdown]').on('click', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopPropagation();
      $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('open');
      $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.dropdown-submenu {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu {
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  margin-top: -6px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
  border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
}

.dropdown-submenu>a:after {
  display: block;
  content: " ";
  float: right;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
  border-left-color: #cccccc;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: -10px;
}

.dropdown-submenu:hover>a:after {
  border-left-color: #555;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
  float: none;
}

.dropdown-submenu.pull-left>.dropdown-menu {
  left: -100%;
  margin-left: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
  border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
}


/*
@media (min-width: 768px) { 
}
@media (min-width: 992px) { 
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) { 
}
*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container pen">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" target="_blank">Brand</a>
          </div>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Active Link</a></li>
              <li><a >Link</a></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Dropdown 1</a></li>
                  <li><a>Dropdown 2</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Dropdown 3</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown 4</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu 4.1</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu 4.2</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu 4.3</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu 4.4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown 5</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu 5.1</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu 5.2</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu 5.3</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Submenu 5.4</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu 5.4.1</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu 5.4.2</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Submenu 5.4.3</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                              <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu 5.4.3.1</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu 5.4.3.2</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu 5.4.3.3</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu 5.4.3.4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                          <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Submenu 5.4.4</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                              <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu 5.4.4.1</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu 5.4.4.2</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu 5.4.4.3</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu 5.4.4.4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Dropdown Link 1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Dropdown Link 2</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Dropdown Link 3</a></li>
                  <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Link 4</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 4.1</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 4.2</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 4.3</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 4.4</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Link 5</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                      <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.1</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.2</a></li>
                      <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.3</a></li>
                      <li class="divider"></li>
                      <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                          <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.1</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.2</a></li>
                          <li class="divider"></li>
                          <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.3</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                              <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.3.1</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.3.2</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.3.3</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.3.4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                          <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.4</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                              <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.4.1</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.4.2</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.4.3</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Dropdown Submenu Link 5.4.4.4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                          </li>
                        </ul>
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </nav>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: not like this..here when clicking submenu..it just slideup right?? i want to stay active with submenu

Comment: When there are no active links we place `href="#"` so when you click on them it automatically scrolls you back

Comment: See for your reference there was nested drop-down. When you click dropdown it will be active as it has nested drop-down which will be active on click

Comment: For your understanding remove `href=#` from your code and check it

Comment: yes..when clicking submenu (city,invoicing frequency etc) is active..but it just doing 
 slideup..

Comment: already i have href path..still not working...active is working fine..but when clicking  submenu slideup

Answer (score 0):

Well, I sincerely hope I finally understood your question.

Basically, you can mark the sub-menu as active if any of its children (`a`) are active. Then you check the sub-menu's *activeness* before sliding it up.

HIH

```js
$(".sidebar-dropdown > a").click(function(e) {
    let parent = $(this).parent();
    let submenu = $(this).next(".sidebar-submenu");
    
    if(!submenu.hasClass('active'))
      if(parent.hasClass('submenu-shown')){
        $(this)
        .next(".sidebar-submenu")
        .slideUp(200, function(){
          parent.removeClass('submenu-shown')
        });
      }else{
        $(this)
        .next(".sidebar-submenu")
        .slideDown(200, function(){
          parent.addClass('submenu-shown')
        });  
      }
});

$('.sidebar-submenu').on('click', 'a', (e) => {
  let submenu = $(e.delegateTarget);
  let a = $(e.currentTarget);
  a.toggleClass('active');
  
  if(submenu.find('a.active').length === 0)
    submenu.removeClass('active');
  else submenu.addClass('active');
  
});
```

```css
.sidebar-submenu{
  display: none
}

.sidebar-submenu li a.active{
  background: red
}

.sidebar-dropdown.active .sidebar-submenu{
  display: block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidebar-menu">
        <ul>
         <li >
             <a href="#">Create Contract</a></li>

          <li class="sidebar-dropdown">
            <a href="#">
             Create Master Data
            </a>
            <div class="sidebar-submenu">
              <ul id="submenu1" class="treeview-menu nav navbar-nav side-nav">
                <li>
                  <a href="#" >City</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#" >Line of business</a>
                </li>

              </ul>
            </div>
         </li>
         <li class="sidebar-dropdown">
            <a href="#">
             Create Master Data 2
            </a>
            <div class="sidebar-submenu">
              <ul id="submenu2" class="treeview-menu nav navbar-nav side-nav">
                <li>
                  <a href="#" >City</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a href="#" >Line of business</a>
                </li>

              </ul>
            </div>
         </li>
```

Comment: in this example why it is not closing(slideup) when clicking create master data

Comment: @becool, it does not allow slide up only when there is an active (red background) item in the sub-menu, meaning the sub-menu is active. exactly what your question asks: *...stop slideup when submenu is active in dropdown...*. if that is not the case, please improve your question explaining exactly what you need

Comment: You can clearly see that there was active item inside master data. It has a submenu

Comment: @becool, well I clearly don't understand what you need. try making the problem clearer in the questions so others can have a better shot. maybe start by defining what you mean by *active sub-menu*

Comment: @Scaramouche for ur example,when i click submenu line of business(now its active thats fine).Then i click  create contract means  i want to slideup the create master data menu(now the code is not sliding up)

Comment: *Then i click create contract means i want to slideup the create master data menu(now the code is not sliding up)* see that's what I mean, there is obviously something I cannot understand about what you want, because that behavior you describe about my example is exactly what I thought you were asking for. When you click *line of business* and it turns red, that means that sub-menu (and by *sub-menu* I mean the `ul` containing it) became active, so it cannot be slid up when clicking *Create master data*, I mean, that's exactly what the title of the question says, so, really, I don't understand

Comment: when i click create contract (this class only active).others all are removed

Comment: @Scaramouche plz check my new image

Comment: @becool, an image is worth a thousand words, well, not this time, I'm gonna need a bit more than that. Please, edit the question and explain what you need as a process, saying the initial state and the transitions wanted, try to be specific. good luck